# How can I construct a correctly formed fictitious-species name

Tags: scientific-names, biology

I'm writing a story in which I want to use a [correctly-formed, binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_nomenclature#Derivation_of_binomial_names) (*Genus species*) Latin name for a fictitious species of vampire bat. I want the name to mean "teeth of death", or something very similar, perhaps using "deadly". Since I'm going to refer to the thing later as *G. species*, or by just using the species part of the binomial name, I'd like to have "teeth" and "death" in the second part of the binomial. When I say I might want to talk about the species-name on its own, I mean in the same way that people talk of "Neanderthal" to mean [Homo neanderthalensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal#Classification).

I originally had *Necrodontinae ecaudata* (*ecaudata* was just a filler that I took from some other bat-species I'd seen). I've since learned that my name has at least three problems! First, *N. ecaudata* hides the "necro" part I want to emphasize. Second, I don't know if my translation makes sense. Last of all, I don't know enough Latin to know if I've obeyed the rules about case, agreement, etc.

What should I, or could I, use? I should say I'm not averse to mixing [Greek and Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_and_Greek_words_commonly_used_in_systematic_names) (as Raymond Dart did with [Australopithecus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australopithecus_africanus)) to keep "necro" rather than something based on "mort".

Comment: The root *necro-* means "corpse" or "dead", rather than "death". How do you feel about *mortiferum* ("death-bearing")?

Comment: Also, you don't need to worry too much about proper Latin in a species name: most biologists don't!

Comment: @Draconis They probably didn't have the advantage of help from the friendly folk on stackexchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the genus, you'd want it to end in -don, like the [Iguanodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iguanodon). Necro- though doesn't mean "deadly', but "dead." Were I a biologist having seen this, I'd think "dead-tooth bat" and presume it had a non-functional tooth or something.

For deadly, you have a few options. You could do *thanatodon* "death-tooth", or perhaps "olethriodon" "deadly-tooth."

Other ideas along the lines of "harm" rather than "death" might be *cacodon* "evil-toothed" or *blabodon*/*blaberodon*, but honestly that would make me think of Slobodan Milošević.

Your genus name is the most identifying feature of a species group. Think *Homo* or *Iguanodon*. I would stick with that, and maybe add *sapiens* if they're human-like.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanatodon sounds like an excellent idea for the genus. If I add on a species identifier that means "tail-less", will "ecaudata" fit correctly with Thanatodon, or does it need to be inflected differently?

Comment: @user02814 For -don, use -us ending instead of -a. In your hypothetical species, *Thanatodon ecaudatus*. Sometimes you'll see them ending in -i or -is, and both of those won't change.